OpenMC Statepoints and Tally
OpenMC is a C++ open-source software for neutron transport calculations.
openmc is an homonymous Python library that binds Python to OpenMC.
I have no training to OpenMC and tried to figured out from the doc and examples and forums/questions online. I have no knowledge in C++ and I tried to figure things out from the Python bindings.
After OpenMC is ran, one gets the result using:
output_file = "./output/statepoint.150.h5"
sp = openmc.StatePoint(output_file)
print("Present", sp.tallies_present)

My issue is the following:
When I run a simulation, the resulting statepoint h5 file has no tally objects (tally_present > 0 returns False). Before running openmc, I have a geometry.xml, a settings.xml and a materials.xml and a tallies.xml. I expected the statepoint file to contain a tally because I defined it beforehand using openmc (Python). Therefore I concluded that some of my setup is incorrect.

What are the requirements for a tally to be "correct"?
In what conditions can a openmc run with a tallies.xml in the folder and not have a tally  in the statepoint h5 file?
Which ways can I explore to understand why my tally is incorrect and troubleshoot?
Can someone write a code snippet for tally/tallies (and necessary objects) in openmc (Python) or a tallies.xml that I can add to any running simulation to test things out?

What I tried:

The examples in the github openmc
The Jupyter in the openmc-notebooks / post-processing.ipynb

And then tried to build a proper tallies.xml.

First of all: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . There is no way anyone can help without having some small sample input and expected output. Then, I guess no C++ experience is needed here, just fluency in python, so just read the documentation, and then debug your code. The docs for StatePoint are pretty straightforward, if tallies_present is false, it means "no user-defined tallies are present" (whatever it means, from physics POV).

@pptaszni : The issue is that posting the materials, the settings, the model would be too long, no? As for your second point, yes this is my point, tallies_present is False, so openmc did not register the tallies.xml correctly and I don't know why

Another remark is that I tried copy pasting the example notebooks and it didn't seem to work (same problem). They can be found here: https://github.com/openmc-dev/openmc-notebooks (I tried multiple times on pandas-dataframes and post-processing.ipynb and I think I copy pasted them correctly but I have the same issue.
